# Libreoffice transforms formula from range reference to table reference

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc

I have a weird problem

Given the following libreoffice calc sheet:

a defined range "myrange" with the contents:

| One | Two | Three |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |

And a formula field:

```
=myrange[Two]
```

The result is `2`

Now: yesterday, I could create such a document in libreoffice, save it as ods, close it, load the file again, and the formular looked as described above. so far, so good.

Today, when I try the same thing, after loading the saved document, the formula has changed. It is now something like `=$Sheet1.$B$2`. Totally weird, especially that I work on a document, save it, all looks good, but when reopening the file, it looks different. I didn't even change the file format.

Between the two tries, I tried exporting the first sheet to Excel xlsx and xls formats, maybe this has change some global settings?

Are there any settings which influence how libreoffice saves formulas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, NOT a solution but I think I know now what happened: I saved the file in xlsx format yesterday, and probably never tried to reload the ods.

It seems that only xlsx is capable of saving this formula. But that formula format is for libreoffice, and excel does not support this kind of references - so weird. As soon as I save it to ods, the formular are saved in translated form (compatible to Excel but in ods format).

So I have the choice between

- excel-compatible ods, which obfuscate the references and makes it very difficult to change or understand them later
- excel-incompatible xlsx, which preserves the formula but loses the data ranges at the same time, so that after 2-3 save/load cycles, all formulas end up in `#NAME?[column]` and I have to search-replace them by the original reference (this is still the best workaround for now)

I'm still hoping for another answer which shows how to save these formulas in ods format :)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 different types of named ranges; they don't really have a different name, which I think is confusing, but that's the way it is. One type is the simply called Named Range, the other type is called Database Ranges. You can access/define them differently:

Named Range: Sheet-->Named Ranges and Expressions-->Define

Database Ranges: Data-->Define Range

To achieve what you want, your formula should be something like this:

`=hlookup("Two", myrange, 2, 0)`

According to documentation "*Database ranges cannot be referenced relative to a base address within a sheet, which is possible with a named range.*" But I found that using the database range in the hlookup formula also works. To be safe though, I would suggest using the Named Range.

Saving and then re-opening the file shows the formula unchanged for me in both range naming methods.